# Exchange 2010 Powershell AutroReply CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, import-csv

I am still rather green with powershell as I am teaching myself, however I cannot seem to get this to work on Exchange 2010, with a list of users in a CSV, and setting the out of office reply.   I am calling a variable $Email in the OOO message, and it never seems to output right. Please help, I am at a loss!

my CSV is simple:

`Users,Email
Test-1,John.J.Smith
Test-2,Sammy.R.Hagar`

```
     $content = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\File\files.csv" -Header "Users", "Email"

    ForEach ($_.Users in $content) {
        Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $_.Users -AutoReplyState enabled -ExternalAudience all -InternalMessage "$_.Users no longer works here, please reach them at $_.Email" -ExternalMessage "$_.Ysers no longer works here, please reach them at $_.Email"
    }

 Exit
```

I have change a few names in this script to make it anonymous, however When I run this script it tells me object "Users" could not be found on my domain. What gives?!?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a headers row in your csv file you should not create new ones with your `Import-CSV`. For the foreach loop you create a new "loop variable" and iterate through the array you created from the csv file.

```
$content = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\File\files.csv" 
ForEach ($Element in $content) {
    Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $Element.Users -AutoReplyState enabled -ExternalAudience all -InternalMessage "$($Element.Users) no longer works here, please reach them at $($Element.Email)" -ExternalMessage "$($Element.Users) no longer works here, please reach them at $($Element.Email)"
}
```

Another approach would be to use the pipeline like this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\File\files.csv" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $_.Users -AutoReplyState enabled -ExternalAudience all -InternalMessage "$($_.Users) no longer works here, please reach them at $($_.Email)" -ExternalMessage "$($_.Users) no longer works here, please reach them at $($_.Email)"
    }
```